# Unexplainable sporadic Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Tags: c#, .net, generics

We've seen a sporadic crash (2 times so far) which I cannot explaint.

Given the following code (reduced to to core):

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  using System;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  public interface IMessage { }

  public class Message : IMessage { }

  public class Response : Message { }

  public class MessageA : Response { }

  public class MessageB : Response { }

  public class MessageC : Response { }

  public class MessageReceived<TMessage> where TMessage : IMessage
  {
    public TMessage Message { get; internal set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ReceiveTimestamp { get; internal set; }
  }

  public sealed class MessageDeserializer<TMessageType> where TMessageType : Message
  {
    public void PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(Message message, DateTimeOffset receiveTimestamp)
    {
      var messageReceivedType = typeof(MessageReceived<>).MakeGenericType(message.GetType());
      dynamic messageReceived = Activator.CreateInstance(messageReceivedType);

      messageReceived.Message = message as dynamic;
      messageReceived.ReceiveTimestamp = receiveTimestamp;

      Console.WriteLine($"Message publish : {messageReceived}, Thread: {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
    }
  }


  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var p = new MessageDeserializer<Response>();

      Task.Run(() => { for (;;) p.PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(new MessageA(), DateTimeOffset.Now);});
      Task.Run(() => { for (; ; ) p.PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(new MessageB(), DateTimeOffset.Now); });
      Task.Run(() => { for (; ; ) p.PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(new MessageC(), DateTimeOffset.Now); });
      Task.Run(() => { for (; ; ) p.PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(new Response(), DateTimeOffset.Now); });
      Task.Run(() => { for (; ; ) p.PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(new Message(), DateTimeOffset.Now); });

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following exception:

> **Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException** Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApp1.MessageA' to
>   'ConsoleApp1.MessageB'  StackTrace: at CallSite.Target(Closure ,
>   CallSite , Object , Object ) at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) at ...

From reading the code there should be no possibility to fail like that.
I also created a console app that calls the function in a loop from multiple threads to see if this might be concurrency related but I cannot reproduce.

Has anybody seen a similar issue or has an idea what might be going wrong?

Full Stack:

```
Type: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException 
Message: Cannot implicitly convert type '[...].MessageRsp' to '[...].MessageErr'  
StackTrace: 
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object ) 
at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) 
at [...].MessageDeserializer`1.PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(Message message, DateTimeOffset receiveTimestamp) in in [...]MessageDeserializer.cs:line 315 
at [...].MessageDeserializer`1.DeserializeMessageBytes(Byte[] messageBytes, Boolean logResponseData) in [...] MessageDeserializer.cs:line 299 
at System.Reactive.AnonymousSafeObserver`1.OnNext(T value) at ReactiveExtensions.Contrib.SingleThreadSynchronizationContext.Run() in [...]
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) 
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) 
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: I tried to submit this on Microsoft Connect but they retired the site: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect

Comment: The Message class is there...

Comment: @mjwills: What do you mean? The code runs fine and it should always do. I cannot explain why it fails in very very rare cases. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show us your actual `PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus` code.

Comment: This is the real code:
    private void PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(Message message, DateTimeOffset receiveTimestamp)
    {
      var messageReceivedType = typeof(MessageReceived<>).MakeGenericType(message.GetType());
      dynamic messageReceived = Activator.CreateInstance(messageReceivedType);
      messageReceived.Message = message as dynamic;
      messageReceived.ReceiveTimestamp = receiveTimestamp;
      this.messageBus.Publish(messageReceived);
    }

Comment: And how do you know crash happened exactly on this line? Do you use line number information from stack trace for that? Maybe you can show complete stack trace?

Comment: Yes - I have the line numbers.
I put the full stack in the original post.

Comment: Try refresh....

Comment: I was going to say that you should not trust line numbers from stack traces too much, but I see `PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus` is last in stack trace, so I honestly have no idea how this can happen with this code you provided. Except I see in stack trace that MessageDeserializer is generic class and in your sample it's not. Does PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus somehow uses generic parameter of `MessageDeserializer`?

Comment: I agree with the line numbers. You made a good point with the generic class. Basically MessageDeserializer is generic of type Response which derives from Message. It's used for a branch in the code:
Message message = null;

if (typeof(TMessageType) == typeof(Command))
{
  message = [...]DeserializeCommand(messageBytes);
}

if (typeof(TMessageType) == typeof(Response))
{
  message = [...]DeserializeResponse(messageBytes);
}

[...]

this.PublishMessageReceivedOnMessageBus(message, receiveTimeStamp);

Comment: Changed the example code to use a generic class to host the publish function. Also added some concurrent tasks to call it. Works like a charm - no crash - no idea why it failed.

Comment: Concurrency should not have any effect. Maybe changing that part to use regular reflection instead of dynamic may shed some light (dynamic uses reflection anyway, so should be not a problem). As of now - I'm out of ideas :) (by the way - `as dynamic` has no effect and can be removed in that line which throws).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evk for your support and assessment! These were exactly my thoughts - this is my I wanted to post this on connect. The only explanation I can think of is a framework bug. Regarding concurrenty: in the orignal code this is even running just on one thread. Regarding the as dynamic: I have the following comment in the code:
// ReSharper disable RedundantCast - dynamic type case cannot be omitted => Unit Test will fail!
I have no explanation why it fails when removed :)

Comment: I recently encountered a similar exception but with a different message. 
Posted the issue on the Microsoft developer community :https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/335489/microsoftcsharpruntimebinderruntimebinderexception.html

Unsure if these are related but I also have no idea what's going on.